# HTML body height - fixed?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the main body of my site to have a fixed height (I think!).

Anyway, the site body is just white, with a border of size 1. Basically, the size of the body is determined by what's in it so, for example, it will resize automatically as more things are added.

What I want is vertical scroll bars so the body doesn't extend forever (is that right?). Should I have a fixed body size?

Answer (score 2):

If you want vertical scroll bars you can use this in your CSS;

```
body {
   height: 900px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden; /* hides the horizontal scroll bar */
}
```

What are you trying to accomplish?  You sound unsure if you even want the scroll bars; is there a reason you want to show the scroll bars instead of just having the browser handle the scrolling when the content gets larger than the window?

Comment: How is this going to be any different that not setting a fixed height to the `body` element? It makes no sense to assign scrollbars to the body element.'

Comment: I agree, in practice, but isn't there different behavior? Without the fixed height, the body element would never show it's own scroll bars (which, I agree, doesn't make much sense as the browser can handle the scrolling fine if it's the whole page).

Comment: The thing is, the bottom border is (at the minute) varying in height, because the content is different on each page - so I guess perhaps I should set a minimum height to start with, if the content goes over this height, the bottom border will enlarge accordingly.

Comment: @tom that sounds right, presuming by "bottom border enlarge" you mean the height of the body element will increase. Though, my understanding of your use case was that you didn't want the height to increase, you want to see scroll bars?

Comment: No, I just explained it badly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need a fixed height

```
body{
height: your-height;
overflow:auto;
}
```

will generate scroll bars only when you overflow the area without growing it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

So, in your body create a layer:

```
<div id="mainbar">
</div>
```

And using CSS you can set the height:

```
div#mainbar {
    min-height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The `min-height` guarantees the initial height that you need. Once it goes over that, it you will automatically have scrollbars. If you would rather the page itself scroll and the body lengthen, just take out the `overflow` line from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the vertical scroll bars to an inner div on your site (like so you can have a footer visible at all times), simple specify the height of the div:

```
#inner { max-height: 300px;
    }
```

I think the default for the overflow is to scroll, but if your content is cutting cut off with no scrollbars, you could also set

```
overflow: auto;
```